# Use of UpdateAsync method ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

My entity looks as follows:

```
public class AddPatientReportDentalChartInput : IInputDto
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(PatientReportDentalChart.TeethDesc)]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int PatientID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual  int TeethNO { get; set; }
    public string SurfaceDefault1 { get; set; }
    public string SurfaceDefault2 { get; set; }
    public string SurfaceDefault3 { get; set; }
    public string SurfaceDefault4 { get; set; }
    public string SurfaceDefault5 { get; set; }
}
```

And the method by which i want to update is:

```
public async Task addPatientReportDentalChart(AddPatientReportDentalChartInput input)
{
    var pid = input.PatientID;
    var chartdetails = _chartReportRepository
                        .GetAll()
                        .WhereIf(!(pid.Equals(0)),
                                   p => p.PatientID.Equals(pid)).ToList();

    if (chartdetails.Count>0)
    {
        //Update should be apply here 
        //please suggest me the solution using updatesync
    }
    else 
    { 
        var patientinfo = input.MapTo<PatientReportDentalChart>();
        await _chartReportRepository.InsertAsync(patientinfo);
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent of `InsertAsync` when I want to update an existing entity? Is there an `UpdateAsync` equivalent method?

Comment: I want simply to update in database using updateSync method like Inserting 
await _chartReportRepository.InsertAsync(patientinfo);

Comment: Use `FindAsync` to look for the entity, modify it, and use `SaveChangesAsync`.

Comment: Will you please suggest me with above code ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating an entity in Entity Framework requires you to retrieve the record, update it and then save changes. It will look roughly like this:

```
public async Task AddPatientReportDentalChartAsync(AddPatientReportDentalChartInput input)
{
    var pid = input.PatientID;
    var chartdetails = _chartReportRepository
                        .GetAll()
                        .WhereIf(!(pid.Equals(0)),
                                   p => p.PatientID.Equals(pid)).ToList();

    if (chartdetails.Count > 0)
    {
        var entity = await _chartReportRepository
                                .YourTableName
                                .FindAsync(entity => entity.SomeId == matchingId);

        entity.PropertyA = "something"
        entity.PropertyB = 1;
        await _chartReportRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else 
    { 
        var patientinfo = input.MapTo<PatientReportDentalChart>();
        await _chartReportRepository.InsertAsync(patientinfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. You saved my whole day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you're using .NET CORE 3.1

```
 public async Task<int> UpdateChat(MChat mChat)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                BDContext.Chat.Update(new Chat
                {
                    Id = mChat.id,
                    UsuarioIdInicia = mChat.usuarioIdInicia,
                    UsuarioIdFinaliza = mChat.usuarioIdFinaliza,
                    EstadoChatId = mChat.estadoChatId
                });
                return BDContext.SaveChanges();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Constantes.ERROR_DETECTADO + ex.InnerException.ToString());
            return Constantes.ERROR_1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: please don't do this. You just block the thread by calling a synchronous `BDContext.SaveChanges()`.
 In case you really want to achieve it, please use `.SaveChangesAsync()` without `Task.Run`

Comment: My friend Task.Run allows u to await...this means it's not gonna block the main thread since it's NOT working synchronously...I could have used .SaveChangesAsync(), but I rather have the entire logic running asynchronously, in case I need to add even more logic...

Comment: @JohnDoe is right, you're just throwing away a thread by doing it this way. Simply using await on the SaveChangesAsync will give you the same results in terms of 'blocking the main thread', but without using 2 threads to do it.

Comment: Ramiro is correct. Because the function is being called in the return statement inside a Task, it won't block the thread.